# Changing Toast to a GridView

Tags: android, layout, gridview, toast

I am trying to display some contacts into a GridView but the example I am using is currently using a Toast. As I am new to Android development so I am just playing with these tools and now I need some help :)

```
private void displayContacts() 
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) 
        {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
            {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                         null, 
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                         new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + " | Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                    pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
public class Test extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        Cursor c = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

        String[] cols = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[]   views = new int[]   {android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                c, cols, views);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is at /res/layout/gridview.xml -->
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:verticalSpacing="10px"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10px"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100px"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Instead of above cursor you can use your own cursor values. And, make sure that you should have on `GridView` in your xml part. Don't forget to add the important permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks mate but I am facing an issue as my (R.layout.Main) is not getting resolved and I am tried my things. I have also removed  Import.android.R; and also Cleaned project many times :( please help.

Comment: For some reason i am still facing the same issue. I am now using a fresh project but still no luck :(

Comment: What issue are you facing? Post here. And, also then, how its working fine for me. [Have a look at here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69670844/Dummy.zip)

Comment: my R.layout.main is not getting resolved but i used your dummy code and it worked perfectly!!! a bit surprising. how can i attach my example with the question??? I am completely new so sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @AliAbid You've to zip that file. And, upload it into any online free hosting file server websites..!!

Answer (score 0):

add the gridView in  ur XML like this::

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

Then in onCreate()method, define that:

```
       gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

now in      `while (pCur.moveToNext())` 
   In an arrayList Store ur required Data;
Then

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```